# Scala sub-modules from SBT project missing on search.maven.org after publishSigned

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, sonatype, maven-central

I've attempted my first publication of [cloakroom](https://gitlab.com/safety-data/cloakroom/), an open source mixed Java/Scala project to sonatype.

The Java sub-modules appear in the Maven central repository search, but the Scala sub-modules are missing.

If I [search for "cloakroom" on search.maven.org](https://search.maven.org/search?q=cloakroom), it returns the Java sub-modules:

- cloakroom
- cloakroom-test-util

It's missing the following Scala sub-modules:

- cloakroom-scala_2.13
- cloakroom-scala-test-util_2.13

However, these seem to be correctly published to Maven: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/safety-data/

The SBT file is [here](https://gitlab.com/safety-data/cloakroom/-/blob/fe98a4094304c3c0e5eda6899b2c6e272e2e8138/build.sbt).
The project includes the following plugin:

```scala
addSbtPlugin("com.github.sbt" % "sbt-pgp" % "2.1.2")
```

The command used to publish was `sbt publishSigned`.

Comment: Did you try downloading the lib from another Maven/SBT project? If it works, I wouldn't bother with it not appearing on Maven search.

Comment: @GaëlJ Yes, it seems to download fine in another SBT project, still I'd like it to appear in search.